# django - not saving in other database with using()

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I am doing this:

```
user = User.objects.create(
    username=username, email=email, is_active=False
)
user.set_password(raw_password=password)
user.save()

for db in settings.DATABASES:
    if 'default' in db:
        print('this is default db, so skip it: ', db)
        continue

    new_user = User(
        username=user.username,
        email=user.email,
        password=user.password,
        is_active=False
    )
    new_user.save(using=db, force_insert=True)
```

I am trying to "sync" one user instance into other databases. I am getting:

```
duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_user_username_key"
```

I know, it is reading from default, to check for duplicates, but even if I have `"force_insert=True"`, it is still checking default database, therefore the error.

what am I missing  here?

Comment: The statement `if 'default' in db:` could be `if 'default' == db:` and to clealry understand do you use `DATABASE_ROUTERS` in project?